# ComposeView inside SwipeRefreshLayout refresh issue

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to migrate a recyclerview to compose Lazy List.

The recyclerview was inside swipeRefreshLayout. So I added the composeView in the xml and added the compose. But when I scroll to the bottom of the list and try to scroll up - swipe to refresh is being triggered. Is there an option to fix this?

```
            <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/refreshLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
                    android:id="@+id/composeUI"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    />
```

Comment: Does it work if you wrap your ComposeView in a NestedScrollView?